# How can I use an external api to authenticate login instead of Django's inbuilt authentication system?

Tags: django, authentication

I am new to Django and working as an intern for a company. I have been tasked with creating an internal software for them to use. The software needs to have a log in system for the employees. However, the company already has an auth api they use for other products. How can I make use of that api  to log the users on? I have searched for an answer for a while and I couldn't find one.

The auth api has an endpoint called '/token' which is used to validate the email and password.
I'm guessing I need to remove the 'django.auth' stuff from settings, but I have no more insight into this than that. Any help would greatly be appreciate.

Below is the swaggerhub documentation for an endpoint of the api:

```
/token:
    post:
      summary: Generate a new token (aka login)
      operationId: createToken
      tags:
        - authentication
      description:
        Login using email and password, and retrieve a newly created bearer token to access our APIs.
        Alternatively, use a token to create another one.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an [Authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#authentication-backends-reference) which will check the given to tokens in your existing token database.

See [Customizing authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I looked at this link before. But i'm not sure I fully understand what I have to do. How will it check whether the tokens exist and to which user they correspond to?